# grep -o and display part of filenames using ls

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a directory which has many directories inside it with the pattern of their name as :
YYYYDDMM_HHMISS
Example: 20140102_120202
I want to extract only the YYYYDDMM part.
I tried `ls -l|awk '{print $9}'|grep -o ^[0-9]*` and got the answer.
However i have following questions:

1. Why doesnt this return any results: `ls -l|awk '{print $9}'|grep -o [0-9]*` . Infact it should have returned all the directories.
   Strangely just including '^' before [0-9] works fine :
   `ls -l|awk '{print $9}'|grep -o ^[0-9]*`
2. Any other(simpler) way to achieve the result?

Comment: The reason `[0-9]*` matches nothing at all is that nothing at all is already a sufficient match, so `grep` stops there. Try `[0-9][0-9]*` or `grep -E '[0-9]+'`, though without the anchor you will match the timestamp, too.

Comment: Be sure to quote the regular expression to prevent the shell from trying to treat it as a pattern. If the shell succeeds, the regex would be replaced with a list of file names matching it.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesnt this return any results: `ls -l|awk '{print $9}'|grep -o [0-9]*`

If there are files in your current directory that start with `[0-9]`, then the shell will expand them before calling `grep`. For example, if I have two files `a1`, `a2` and `a3` and run this:

```
ls | grep a*
```

After the filenames are expanded, the shell will run this:

```
ls | grep a1 a2 a3
```

The result of which is that it will print the lines in `a2` and `a3` that match the *text* "a1". It will also ignore whatever is coming from stdin, because when you specify filenames for `grep` (2nd argument and beyond), it will ignore stdin.

Next, consider this:

```
ls | grep ^a*
```

Here, `^` has no special meaning to the shell, so it uses it verbatim. Since I don't have filenames starting with `^a`, it will use `^a*` as the pattern. If I did have filenames like `^asomething` or `^another`, then again, `^a*` would be expanded to those filenames and `grep` would do something I didn't really intend.

This is why you have to quote search patterns, to prevent the shell from expanding them. The same goes for patterns in `find /path -name 'pattern'`.

As for a simpler way for what you want, I think this should do it:

```
ls | sed -ne 's/_.*//p'
```

Answer (score 3):

To show only the YYDDMM part of the directory names:

```
for i in ./*; do echo $(basename "${i%%_*}"); done
```

Not sure what you want to do with it once you've got it though...

Comment: Yes, much cleaner, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You must avoid parsing `ls` output.

Simple is to use this printf:

```
printf "%s\n" [0-9]*_[0-9]*|egrep -o '^[0-9]+'
```